# Регулярное выражение на числа + буквы либо буквы, но не числа

Tags: регулярные-выражения, синтаксический-анализ

Ищу регулярное выражение, срабатывающее для чисел и букв/букв, но не срабатывающее для чисел.

Как это проделать?
Пример:

```
asdfdasf = true 
dasfasdf1234 = true
1234dafsasd=true
231234 = false

[a-zA-Z\d]+ проблема этого выражения в том что 23124 = true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Хочется регулярку, можно регулярку. Но только две. Первая `[a-zA-Z\d]+`, вторая `[a-zA-Z]+`. а потом просто делаете условие `(результат_первой && !результат второй)`.

**UPD:**
Если немного подумать, то стает понятным, что должна быть хотя бы одна буква. Поэтому рождается вот такое

```
[a-z\d]+[a-z][a-z\d]+
```

Если нужны и большие буквы, то это легко исправляется.

```
[A-Za-z\d]*[A-Za-z][A-Za-z\d]*
```

Comment: Это хороший вариант, но я не могу так сделать так как пишу их внутри flex файла. Пытаюсь получить небольшой лексический анализатор для файла с настройками.

Comment: так вы бы повесили тэг окромя регулярки ;)

Comment: http://flex.sourceforge.net/manual/Patterns.html#Patterns вот православный мануал, но я что-то не могу пока вкурить его как следует.

Comment: сейчас проверю UPD

Comment: @Kovadim Да спасибо, оно сработало. Сотни нефти с меня.

Comment: теперь раскурите выражение:)

Answer (score 2):

```
/^(?:\w+|\w+\d+\w*|\w*\d+\w+)$/
```

Срабатывает только в случае: 
букв, 
либо вначале хотя бы одна буква, дальше хотя бы одно число и возможно дальше буквы, 
либо возможно буквы, дальше хотя бы одно число, после которого хотя бы одна буква.

Это PCRE.

Comment: Спасибо, но я собрал уже нужный парсер. Съедает мегабайтный ini файл за полторы секунды. Может кому-то еще потребуется Ваш регэксп.

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю, но мне кажется, что для таких целей регулярка не нужна. Достаточно просто проверить значение функцией [is_numeric()](http://www.php.ru/manual/function.is-numeric.html) или [is_int()](http://www.php.ru/manual/function.is-int.html)

Comment: Спасибо, но мне нужно именно регулярное выражение, так как я работаю не c PHP